# How to Lower Poly count while keeping borders the same shape...I want to reduce polys internally but keep my edges and borders unchanged

Tags: modeling, edges, baking, normal-map, remesh

Zbrush has a "freeze borders" option.  Does blender have a way to keep my edges and borders of a mesh "frozen" in place while reducing the internal polys?  I have a large mesh with weird non-symmetrical geometry and many non-symmetrical holes in it.  I need not only my outside borders but my inside borders (the borders of the holes) to keep their exact shapes after reducing the polycount of the mesh.  I don't care if my edges have a higher poly count in order to achieve this...I just want all of my borders to have exactly the same shape after reducing the poly count so that I can try to go from high poly to low poly and bake a normal map.  I'm new to blender...I hope that this question is ok.  Here is a picture...[image]

Comment: Perhaps X > Limited Dissolve and play with the Max Angle parameter in the Operator box but maybe show an image of your mesh?

Comment: Sorry...I have added a picture...I hope that this helps.  I need the shape of the holes to not change but I have way too many verts...I need to decimate and bake a normal map but I need to not change my shape.  I hope that this isn't too noob of a question!  Thank you for responding...

Comment: Oh ok for an organic object you could try the Remesh tools for example: Select your object, duplicate and keep the copy somewhere, then in the Object Data panel > Remesh, try the 2 options, Voxel and Quad

Comment: Thank you!  I will try those!